# DNS server not found

Tags: visual-studio, iis, github

I really hope somebody can help me, because I *have* to make this work until tomorrow morning, or my boss will be very angry.

Through Visual Studio I am connected to github, where there is several projects. On my localhost I am using IIS. My boss showed me how to set up one of the projects today, and that works 100%. He wanted me to set up the next project from github. I have all the files in Visual Studio. I went to IIS and binded my project:

```
Type             Host            Port          IP-address
http         casestudy.local     80            *
```

But when I go to my localhost http://casestudy.local i get the following error:
The DNS address for casestudy.local server could not be found.

Does anybody knows what I can do to make it work? The other project is working fine, so it is defently something I am doing wrong with setting up the project.

i cross my fingers that somebody can help me.

**UPDATE**

i have been in the path and added the local dns server, like the other project: 
Local DNS server:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

and added:

```
127.0.0.1   casestudy.local
```

Now I get this error:
HTTP-error 403.14 - Forbidden

Update 2:
Konfigurations error in :

```
<assemblies>
    <remove assembly="System.Web.Http" />
    <remove assembly="System.Net.Http" />     
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
     <add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</assemblies>
```

Best Regards

Comment: why would you use local, i ponder. do you have any pages in your IIS website? why do you think gihub has anything to do with IIS?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A "little" mistake from my side sorry. I have my Github Repotories locally on my computer of course. I have 1 on my ISS site which is working fine, on the path http://travel.local

Comment: that is not a DNS server, that is a host file, the host file overrides domain names in the local host. The IIS website setting should have your website folder (the one with the pages) configured, Such folder could be the project folder. The application pool account in IIS should have permissions to such folder

Comment: ok, imagine that your project has only one page: index.html in your repository. In IIS go to the site Basic Settings and point the Physical Path to your local repository. Make sure the AppPool has permissios to read that folder.

Comment: Thank you a lot Richardo. I did that now, and it seems like something is happening now. I got another error. I just updated my question with the error. It is in the webconfig, but maybe it is to hard for you to say with the small code?

Comment: no problem. The configuration error is gonna be more tricky. First You may want to create  a new question since is a completely different issue. Second, post the full error, Third, I speculate that the problem is that you need additional component installed from Your Windows "Turn Windows Features on or off", like .net 4.5 or some other component.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. It defently helped me some of the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the Basic Settings for the site in question. Set the Physical
2. Path to you project files folder.
3. Take note of the Application Pool
   being used.
4. Verify that the account used by that application pool
   has read permission to your project's folder.

[image: IIS Configuration]